# Auth::attempt equivalent in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, laravel-4, doctrine-orm

In Laravel there is a simple `Auth::attempt(...` method available. I'm trying to find the equivalent in Symfony.

I have a doctrine user entity that has implemented `AdvancedUserInterface`. I've been reading through the Symfony security docs, but I just want take a very simple POST request, authenticate the user for the session, and respond with a JSONResponse.

Is there a simple approach I'm missing? Do I need to write some sort of custom provider or...?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html + http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html + http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/firewall.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to install [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) and use their LoginManager. In your controller you will need an authentication method that will look something like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccountStatusException;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;

/**
 * Authenticate a user with Symfony Security
 *
 * @param \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface        $user
 * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response $response
 */
protected function authenticateUser(UserInterface $user, Response $response)
{
    try {
        $this->container->get('fos_user.security.login_manager')->loginUser(
            $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name'),
            $user,
            $response);
    } catch (AccountStatusException $ex) {
        // We simply do not authenticate users which do not pass the user
        // checker (not enabled, expired, etc.).
    }
}
```

The long answer is to build a lite version of FOSUserbundle yourself.

1. Create a UserProvider class. Laravel already comes with 2 UserProviders: Illuminate\Auth\DatabaseUserProvider and Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider. Symfony Security Component ships only with an in-memory user provider. Here is a recipe on how to do this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html. Also a note on this: because you are using Doctrine, you can make the UserRepository your UserProvider class.
2. (Optional, depends on what you're trying to do) Define a new firewall in app/config/security.yml
3. In your controller, create this:

   ```
   use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
   use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

   protected function authenticateUser($firewallName, UserInterface $user) {
       $this->get('security.user_checker')->checkPostAuth($user);

       $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $firewallName, $user->getRoles());

       if ($this->container->isScopeActive('request')) {
           $this->get('security.authentication.session_strategy')->onAuthentication($this->container->get('request'), $token);
       }

       $this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
   }
   ```

or you might better want to move this to an authentication service provider and call this service into your controller action.

Hope this helps.